# Google sheet track cell value over time

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where I want to track the value of a cell over time and save the previous results. The standard =if() formula is actually if/else and will overwrite previous data. I searched for a way to stop the execution of a formula (to turn the if/else into a standalone if) along the lines of =if(today()=A1,value,Do Nothing). The following:

```
      A              B
1. 7/27/17   =if(today()=A1,value,"")
2. 7/28/17   =if(today()=A2,value,"")
3. 7/29/17   =if(today()=A3,value,"")
```

generates this on 7/27/17:

```
      A        B
1. 7/27/17   value
2. 7/28/17   
3. 7/29/17
```

and on 7/28/17 it will be this:

```
      A        B
1. 7/27/17   
2. 7/28/17   value
3. 7/29/17
```

Anyone know how to get to this on the 28th?

```
      A        B
1. 7/27/17   value
2. 7/28/17   value
3. 7/29/17
```

Comment: Either with code or circular references.  You will need to change the `""` to refer to itself and allow circular references and change the iterations to 1.

Comment: Nevermind, you cannot allow circular references in google sheets, only Excel.

Comment: So the only way in google sheets is with code.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to tackle this with code?

Comment: Do not tag with Excel if you use Google Sheets. They are not the same. Removing the Excel tag.

Comment: Were you able to do this? If so, can you post that as an Answer?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you can do this in google sheets though you have to go into the settings to allow iterative calculations.

File -> Spreadsheet settings -> Calculation -> Iterative calculation [On]

Before this setting was changed the value of B1 =if(today()=A1,value,B1) would raise an error. With the setting it will now retain the previous value.